Latex: Add pdf page without split the text content
I want to add a pdf page to my current latex pdf file, but i got a problem. When i use \includepdf, then the position where i put this command will auto add a pagebreak, like the image below.

This is what i want:


But this is what i get:


I want that when i use \includepdf command, the rest of text content will continue to fill in the rest blank of current page until end of page, even the included pdf page is now in the next page. But this command add a pagebreak instead.

I try to use \includegraphics and set all margin=0pt, but the size of included pdf page is too long to fit to the page. I want to keep the original size of included pdf page, too. The command \includepdf[pages={1},width=\paperwidth,fitpaper]{<pdf_name>} with fitpaper can do it, but the only problem is what i have described above.

I try to add pagecommand to \includepdf, too, but this happen that the text content is directly writen on the included pdf page. I also want to avoid this problem.

Anyone help me!

@cfr thank you. I have solve it by using afterpage package. Just replace the \includepdf with a command
\afterpage{
\clearpage
\includepdf....
\clearpage
}

Sorry, didn't read carefully enough. You probably want to put the \includegraphics into a figure environment. But it depends what you want. Do you want it to go to the top of the next page regardless? Or would you prefer it to be placed somewhere on this page, if possible? If you want it on a page of its own, try \begin{figure}[p]\centering\includegraphics{}\end{figure}, but if the image is actually page size, your solution may work fine.
